Overriding DRF ListAPIView list() method
I have a DRF Project, which has a ListAPIView for a model called Category. This model, has a ForeginKey to itself named parent_category and with related name of subcategories. I want my URLs to behave like this:

get a list of Categories with no parent:
example.com/api/categories
get a list of subcategories of an object with some id:
example.com/api/categories/{id_here}

models.py:
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent_category = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                        related_name='subcategories')

views.py:
class CategoryList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer

And I have no idea how to write my urls.py. Do I need DRF routers? or Django path works fine? I don't know which to choose or how to use them for this project. I thought if I override ListAPIMixin's list() method, it would work, but I don't even know what to write in that.

I made a dummy project for myself and implemented it like this
You can do this by rewriting get_queryset
example code
views
from .models import Category
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView
from .serializers import CategorySerializer


class CategoryViewSet(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    def get_queryset(self):    
        parent_category = self.kwargs.get("parent_category") or None
        return Category.objects.filter(parent_category=parent_category)

urls
you can set  multiple-routes option
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from cate.views import CategoryViewSet

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', CategoryViewSet.as_view() ,name="category"),
    path('<int:parent_category>/', CategoryViewSet.as_view() ,name="category"),
    
]

Serializers
from .models import Category
from rest_framework import serializers


class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = "__all__"

also see DRF-Filtering
Maybe it will be useful for you

Let me ask a question: Why is it called "ViewSet" in DRF? is it just a simple naming convention or is it technically different than conventional Django views?

You are free to choose any name you want but for Readability and maintenance your program is better to use clean code I recommend you to read the clean code book
